# I have google play account but dont want to share account credentials, but want to send statistics from google play acount of my app

Tags: android

I have google play developers account and I had made some apps for client. In this account I have app statistics such as how many downloads, which devices, which countries. Clients want that app details but i don't want to give credentials of my account to client.

Can i send those info by mail every week?

Is there is way to send information of by mail all statistics and graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look on this video . you will get information's. but we dont have any API for this .

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dr5sGLY210Q

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139628

Hope this will help you .

Comment: this is not helped lot to my question .... still accepted your because these links are helpful .